# iMessage current user's name is nil

Tags: ios, swift, imessage-extension

I am creating iMessage application. My problem is that I do not know how to get the current user's name.

I tried like this:

```
"\(conversation.selectedMessage?.senderParticipantIdentifier.uuidString) Sent You A Challenge"
```

And like that:

```
"\(conversation.localParticipantIdentifier.uuidString) Sent You A Challenge"
```

But both of those are "`nil`". Is it the right way to get the username?

Comment: I kinda wanna see the code before it, ensure your conversation and selected message aren't nil?

Comment: @StephenJ I added the full function. I am absolutely sure, the selected message and conversation is not nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the "`$`" sign prefixing.

To get the name of the local user: `$\(conversation.localParticipantIdentifier.uuidString)`

> WARNING!

If you try to print it, it is simply `UUID` without the name.
The thing is that Message app will replace them with the contact’s actual name before showing them to the user.